# Whats the difference between a peer and an organization? How can i be sure how many peers i have on a organization?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

For my summer internship, I recently began learning about blockchain in Hyperledger Fabric.
However, I'm still not entirely clear on a few things. I mean, I understand everything, but when I try to connect all the concepts, I just get lost.

The difference between an organization and a peer still confuses me.
How do I know how many peers my organization might require?
Maybe I'll use an example to make it easier to understand.

Consider that I had two Organizations: a corn farm and a supermarket.

My goal is to build a network that will track all crucial information on the corn. A customer entering the supermarket will therefore understand where my corn originated.

In this scenario, I just need one peer per Organization, am I correct? Or what if I could have two peers in each Organization, but who would they be? Is it possible for me to have two peers in each organization, with one dealing with orders and the other with their arrivals?

I don't know; I'm just confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An organization entails a group of clients, peers, and orderers that have a common administration.

The entire purpose of Fabric is to facilitate collaboration and consensus between organizations that do not trust each other.

An organization can have as many clients, peers and orderers as you want as long as it makes sense.

In your corn farm and supermarket example, the corn farm can have an organization of its own, and the supermarket can be another organization.

You would probably want at least two peers in the organization, for purpose of load balancing and high availability.

Comment: Thank you. And if you could explain also how i can define my ordering nodes?!

Comment: Take a look at the https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples repository, and play with some of its tutorials / samples. An ordering node is configured somewhat similar to a peer node, only difference is that each ordering node needs to be registered in the channel config, unlike the peers that do not need that.